# Defining function in python with a special character

Tags: python

I'm using an IRC bot in which I can define my own commands in a module with the following:

```
def saa(args):
```

I'd like to be able to use `def sää(args):` since I'm Finnish people will be using it and "Sää" means weather, but this throws an invalid syntax error.

Is there any way to do this in python?

Comment: Use Python3, not possible in Python2.

Comment: I'd suggest to always program in English (function/variable/etc names, as well as comments), and only do the localization on the outer layer, towards actual users (i.e., not other programmers). It makes thing a lot easier whenever, for example, you'd like to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifiers in Python 2.x can only use `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` (except as first character) and `"_"`, as per the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Identifiers in Python 3.x can use a wider range ([language reference](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)), and `def sää(args):` would be acceptable.